# Vagrantfile opening in SublimeText by default as Ruby extended file

Tags: vagrant, sublimetext3

On top of my `Vagrantfile` I have:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
```

But every time when I open the file, I have to select manually in SublimeText 3 that I wanna set the syntax to Ruby, so it'll be readable.

How can you set a filename to be opened as a ruby-file in this example. Because the file has no extension.

Answer (score 8):

Your use case is exactly what [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) is written to address. In fact, I believe Vagrantfile is one of the default "samples", so you might not have to do anything. Also, comments that are handled in some special way on some editors does not apply to all editors (in this case, ST).

Comment: Yup, installing ApplySyntax will immediately recognize vagrant files.